Value of top offset seems to be taken from sibling element
I have the following html/css (see snippet below) which demonstrates a fixed header.
I noticed that before explicitly setting the value of top to the header: top: 0px; its value is taken from the margin-top of the section and is 120px.
This is seen in Chrome devtools (from  header element):

I am not sure why that is. Can someone please explain and provide a relevant pointer to the documentation?
Thanks in advance.


header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

section {
  margin-top: 120px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/header-footer.style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
  <h1>This is my header</h1>
</header>
<section>
  <article>
    <h2>First article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl
      typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin
      coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub
      hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Second article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl
      typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin
      coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub
      hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Third article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl
      typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin
      coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub
      hammock.</p>

    <p>Cray food truck brunch, XOXO +1 keffiyeh pickled chambray waistcoat ennui. Organic small batch paleo 8-bit.
      Intelligentsia umami wayfarers pickled, asymmetrical kombucha letterpress kitsch leggings cold-pressed squid
      chartreuse put a bird on it. Listicle pickled man bun cornhole heirloom art party.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Fourth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl
      typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin
      coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub
      hammock.</p>
  </article>

  <article>
    <h2>Fifth article</h2>

    <p>Tacos actually microdosing, pour-over semiotics banjo chicharrones retro fanny pack portland everyday carry vinyl
      typewriter. Tacos PBR&B pork belly, everyday carry ennui pickled sriracha normcore hashtag polaroid single-origin
      coffee cold-pressed. PBR&B tattooed trust fund twee, leggings salvia iPhone photo booth health goth gastropub
      hammock.</p>
  </article>
</section>
</body>
</html>




That's simply what happens with absolute or fixed positioning, when you don't specify a value for either of the two "opposite" sides, but leave them at their default auto - the element then gets absolute/fixed positioned, in the exact place it would be in normal flow, without positioning. And the calculated value you are looking at, reflects that.

Thanks @C3roe! Can you please confirm this behavior is to do with collapsing margins as suggested by the duplicate?

Yes, collapsing margins are what's making the "default" position of the header what it is here. If you removed the margin-top from the section, everything will move up. The header will still have a calculated top of around 20px then, because then the h2 in the first article in the section still provides a margin-top, that collapses through.

Can you tell me which margins collapse then? The top one of the header with the top one of the section? I thought margin collapse only applied to a bottom one with a top one...

No, it can apply when only top margins are involved as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_box_model/Mastering_margin_collapsing
